# Login screen won't accept my password

Tags: password, users, login-screen

I recently upgraded to 12.04 from 11.10 and since upgrading have been unable to log in to my user profile. The upgrade went okay and I can login to a guest session fine but whenever I try to login to my profile, after entering my password, I just return to the login screen.  I've changed my password in Root (`passwd <username>`) and can log in to tty1 with no issues, it's just in GUI I'm having problems.

I'm using a HP dv7 laptop, 32-bit Ubuntu install, Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU P7350 @ 2.00GHz × 2, Nvidia graphics.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Try these solutions:

From your cli remove the .Xauthority file. Some people have reported that they also needed to remove the .xsession-errors files.

```
sudo rm .Xauthority
sudo rm .xsession-errors*
```

Finally some people have reported that ownership and permissions on their home folders were set incorrect. Not sure if this will help but it's worth checking:

```
ls -l /home
```

you may have to give ownership back to your account using chown

```
sudo chown -R username:group /home/username
```

Answer (score 0):

These are all valid questions from the other thread, you haven't answered them yet.

- Switch to the text console `[Ctrl][Alt][F1]`
- Login with your username / password
- Check for errors, write them down word for word. Did you enter your home directory?
- Check the output for `ls -l /home`. Does it say `drwx` at the start of the line, notice especially the `w`?
- Check for nearly full filesystems `df -h`
- Type `exit`
- Switch to the graphics console `[Ctrl][Alt][F7]`
- If you had any errors on the text console, add them to your question.

Answer (score 0):

To throw another idea in here. None of the above helped me, so I installed a new display manager (gdm3, lightdm, etc.).

Edit: Not sure why all the down-votes. I know it's not the best solution, but it may work for some. If you're going to down-vote, at least leave me a comment.