# X crash at login for 1 user

Tags: xorg, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Login screen won’t accept my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129610/login-screen-wont-accept-my-password)

User switching wasn't working on my 12.04 LTS desktop (just dropped me to TTY8 with a blinking cursor) so I tried to manually start a second X session by logging in to TTY6 and running `startx -- :1`. This didn't work either, and my machine locked up.

Now when I try to log in as the second user from LightDM, X instantly crashes and I'm thrown back to the login screen. Other accounts on the machine work fine, and it happens for every desktop environment.

I've had a poke around in my home directory, but I can't see anything obvious to change/delete to get it working again.  Can anyone advise please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the file ~/.Xauthority for the problematic user had changed owership, and was owned by root.

`sudo chown user:user ~/.Xauthority` changed the ownership back to the original user. After that, I could log in without a problem.